# Why does SIFT create an image pyramid?

Tags: computer-vision, feature-detection, sift

My understanding is that SIFT is made scale invariant by using different scales for the gaussian smoothing, why is an image pyramid also used?

Comment: what answers are you looking for that aren't addressed in the SIFT paper? what is your understanding of image pyramids?

Comment: My understanding is that the spread of the gaussian is used to produce scale invariance, I do not understand why both scale changes and an image pyramid is used(though some sources don't appear to say the image is down sampled).

Comment: because the pyramid reduces the amount of data to... sift through. sufficiently lowpassed data can be safely *decimated* with no loss in information (from the decimation).

Comment: So is the orientation and descriptor computed in the resampled image?